# Autoscaling Axes in Matplotlib Problems - Graph Disappears

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a way to visualize data that changes drastically over a few years, and I'm using the code below to do so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_pickle('/path/to/pickle file')

y = data['Total'].values
x = list(range(len(y)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot([],[], '-')

#ax.set_xlim(np.min(x), np.max(x))
#ax.set_ylim(np.min(y), np.max(y))


def animate(i):
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    line.set_xdata(x[:i])
    line.set_ydata(y[:i])

    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Everything above essentially works as intended, however when actually graphing the data, I get the correct autoscaling of the x and y axes as time progresses, but no line can be seen in the final picture of the graph below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS2PB.jpg

However, zooming in (even slightly) allows the lines to appear (below):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBiaH.jpg

It's not an issue with line width, as even setting it to an absurdly large number still doesn't display the graph until zoomed in, so I'm not entirely sure what's going on/how to fix this.

I'd like to be able to see a 'seemingly' fixed width line appear during the animation like the zoomed in picture above.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change `line, = ax.plot([],[], '-')` and actually plot the first value of your dataset before calling FuncAnimation ?

Comment: You could make this question better by making it complete: providing some mock data to illustrate the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve